# Is it possible to have 2 or more PVC in a statefulset?

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, statefulset

I have a statefulset from mongo with 2 volumemounts:

```
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mongo-persistent-storage
              mountPath: /data/db
            - name: mongo-config-storage
              mountPath: /data/configdb
```

I want to know how to add the second volume in volumeClaimTemplates:

```
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: mongo-persistent-storage
      annotations:
          volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: "sc-infra"
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 2Gi
```

Comment: the thing is called volumeClaimTemplates (plural) and it contains an array or objects. So it certainly is possible to specify more than one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just append additional claim to your `volumeClaimTemplates`. Example:

```
volumeClaimTemplates:
- metadata:
    name: mongo-persistent-storage
    annotations:
       volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: "sc-infra"
  spec:
    accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
    resources:
      requests:
        storage: 2Gi
- metadata:              # <-- append another claim
    name: mongo-config-storage
  spec:
    storageClassName: sc-infra
    accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
    resources:
      requests:
        storage: 1Gi
```